# Where does the OwnedName type come from?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rust

I am trying to parse an XML file in rust using rust-xml and am having trouble matching on the name of the tag:

```
for e in parser.events() {
    match e {
        XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes: _, namespace: _ } => {
            match name {
                "LexicalEntry" => {
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
enter codesrc/main.rs|127 col 21| 127:35 error: mismatched types:
||  expected `xml::name::OwnedName`,
||     found `&'static str`
|| (expected struct `xml::name::OwnedName`,
||     found &-ptr) [E0308]
|| src/main.rs:127                     "LexicalEntry" => {
||                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 here
```

I find this surprising because the OwnedName identifier doesn't show up anywhere in the code or dependencies for my project (including the rust sources!):

> $ rgrep OwnedName . Binary file ./woordenboek/src/.main.rs.swp matches
>   ./woordenboek/src/main.rs:
>   //xml::name::OwnedName("LexicalEntry") => { Binary file
>   ./woordenboek/target/debug/deps/libxml-5882f08ff8adc5e5.rlib matches

Where is this OwnedName type that I'm supposed to match against coming from?  Is the compiler inventing some type and inserting it into the xml library for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml::name::OwnedName` is the type of the `name` field of the `XmlEvent::StartElement` variant, not `&'static str` (a string literal).

Comment: On my machine, that variant is just a "Name."  So I think this is some weirdness with Cargo.  It seems the code Cargo has checked out for rust-xml isn't the same version that built the rlib that found it's way into my binary.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very sorry that I didn't put API documentation for `xml-rs` anywhere yet :( I'll try to fix this as soon as I can.

**Update** fixed that, you can find the latest documentation [here](http://netvl.github.io/xml-rs/xml/index.html). For example, here is [`OwnedName`](http://netvl.github.io/xml-rs/xml/name/struct.OwnedName.html).

`OwnedName` is a separate structure because XML names are not just strings - they consist of local name, namespace URI and optional prefix, so they have special representation. In order to check the local name only you can use `local_name` field of `OwnedName` which is a `String`:

```
for e in parser.events() {
    match e {
        XmlEvent::StartElement { name, attributes: _, namespace: _ } => {
            match &name.local_name[..] {
                "LexicalEntry" =>
```